# how do I run an msi with SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS without restart

Tags: windows, security, cmd, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to install a driver with a remote framework that lets me run shell commands spawned as children of the remoting/monitoring app on the remote machine, run as cmd /c "command". But the driver refuses to install due to a security feature which thinks the driver may be unsafe.

The driver also has quotes(spaces in path) so its something like

```
Dim command: command =  "\\\\server\\driver\\folder\\Autorun.exe" /passive   /norestart";
Set retVal = remote.Shell(command)
```

which runs

```
cmd /c " "\\server\driver\folder\Autorun.exe" /passive /norestart"
```

on the remote machine

I've tried and have had trouble using setx SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS 1 /m in a previous statement, I'm guessing that the subprocess don't see new global enviromental variables that weren't around when it's parent started, and won't work without a restart. I'd like to avoid a restart.

I tried running

```
cmd /c " set SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS=1 & "\\server\driver\folder\Autorun.exe" /passive /norestart"
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting "Launch applications and unsafe files" to enabled for Internet zone in Internet Explorer options under security(custom level) and then exporting the changes from HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3 to a registry file and adding it with regedit /s.

After that I can run the installer of the shared drive.

One of these days I'll pare the registry file down to the minimum I guess.

P.S. I believe this causes IE to default to a warning page on startup.

Answer (score 3):

You got a bit lost on the way SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS is used.  It is not an environment variable and cannot be tinkered with from the command prompt, it is an option for [ShellExecuteEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A winapi function that you indeed use to start programs.  It isn't very clear what programming tools you have access to, using it in a batch file or VBScript isn't going to work.  You'd need at least, say, VB.NET and pinvoke the function.  You can get the required declarations from the pinvoke.net web site.

Let's talk about what's really going on, you might find a simpler solution.  When you download a file from an Internet web site, Windows adds an extra stream to the file that indicates where the file came from.  Which basically states "this file did not come from a safe place" and makes the driver installer balky.  Which is rather an important feature if you think about it, your user is going to install software that can do a *lot*, you pretty much have free reign of the machine if you can get a driver installed.

If you right-click the file in Explorer and click Properties then you'll see this at the bottom of the window:

[image]

All that's needed is to click that Unblock button.  So this is a simple way for your user to solve the problem.  You could document the extra step in the install instructions.  Also with the advantage that it is now the user that took responsibility of allowing potentially unsafe code to be installed.

Other ways to get the file unblocked is with PowerShell's [Unblock-File command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849924.aspx) and the SysInterals' [streams utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx), -d option.

And you probably ought to consider the option of writing your own installer.  Which will keep the driver packaged in the setup file so it won't be tinkered with by Windows.  And the user gets the warning when he starts the installer instead.  And it can be signed so the user has some confidence in where the file came from and that it didn't get messed with on its way to his machine.  There are many utilities that help you write an installer, like InstallAware, InstallShield, NSIS, etcetera.

Comment: I'm trying to automate driver install from a remote shared drive one of the drivers is giving me trouble.

Comment: so would the simplest thing to do would be call a powershell script that pinvokes  ShellExecuteEx()?

Comment: There isn't say a simple way to disable all zone checks?(note this is on an insecure testing box)

Comment: Just see my answer above. Hans ist not exactly correct, when stating that it could not be done with 'SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS' as an env. variable. Well, he is a programmer, not an admin :-) Nevertheless both methods are worth mentioning.

Comment: A surprise to programmers everywhere. SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS is not just a flag, it is also a valid environment variable and its documented in KB 889815.

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ to Hans' answer:

Of course, SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS **is** as well a predefined environment variable. Changing it in a process and then starting a child process (e.g. msiexec.exe) which by defaults inherits the environment, has just the same result as using ShellExecuteEx() and providing SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS as a parameter to the SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure. The first method is preferred by admins or quick hacks, e.g. if you work with batch or script files which set the environment variable- or when the final call to the .msi file lying on the unsafe network drive is not done by your own code.

For example:

```
@echo off    
set SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS=1
call msiexec.exe /i "\\MY_UNC_DRIVE\installs\mysetup.msi /qb /L*v "c:\logs\mysetup.log"
call "\\MY_UNC_DRIVE\installs\Just_another_setup.exe"
```

If you already use a ShellExecuteEx() in your code, then of course, go with the parameter as Hans mentioned, because this implementation it is more closed. (If you use CreateProcess(), think about using ShellExecuteEx() instead.

Getting back to the environment variable(s). Generally you cannot influence the environment of already started processes. You can set the default environment used by NEW processes by the "setx" command used in the question. **But with "setx" you don't change the environment for your current process.This was the problem in question.** For this you have to use "set" as shown. So either use both commands after each other or don't use setx at all because for running a setup on foreign machines, it is not clean to make permanent security changes without asking.

For more details on permanent changes/admin point of view, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/595211/removing-the-open-file-security-warning-in-windows-8/934283#934283

Important: As mentioned, there is no general way in Windows to influence processes which *already* run (only own-defined inter-process-communication maybe), so it is important to set the environment variable *before* starting the setup to be influenced.

One more thing: Some people think, one must use "SETLOCAL" in a batch file. Normally this is not necessary. Environment changes with "set" are not permanent, and do not incluence "other" processes- they are only inherited to subprocesses and, partly, to superprocesses. But, when the caller on first level ends, the environment is reverted to original state again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put everything within the same quotation:

```
cmd /c "set SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS=1 & \\server\driver\folder\Autorun.exe /passive /norestart"
```

You can try these and see the difference in the output:

```
cmd /c "echo foo & echo bar"
cmd /c "echo foo" & "echo bar"
```